# Windows Update fails with code 80244019

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I just found that Windows Update is failing and hasn't installed any updates for a little more than a month.

It says:

```
Windows could not search for new updates
There was a problem searching for updates
Errors found: Code 80244019
```

This article at Microsoft suggests it might be a virus: [Windows Update error 80070422, 80244019, or 8DDD0018](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/windows-update-error-80070422-80244019-or-8ddd0018)

The operating system is Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center.

Comment: 80244019 = WU_E_PT_HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND (Same as HTTP status 404 - the server cannot find the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). This looks like a network issue

Comment: I agree with @magicandre1981 that it most likely is a network issue, perhaps on the Windows Server  end.  I've had luck in the past by just waiting a bit for said Windows problem to clear up....YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [an online discussion](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f320/windowsupdate_80244019-or-windowsupdate_dt000-1024706.html) that suggests that this has been happening because of increased load of Windows 10 distribution.

What worked for me was disabling "Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows".

Comment: I did: "(...) disabling use of Windows Update for updating other Microsoft Products might fix it. In fact, it worked."

Comment: @Ramhound I fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

What worked for me was going into services.msc and restarting the 2 services bits and windows update services; Background Intelligent transfer service.

Comment: This answer just helped me under Windows 7 Professional x64 edition, thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for me on Server 2008r2

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 8.0

Comment: Also works on Server 2012R2.

Answer (score -1):

I disabled my antivirus and this seemed to help.