# Windows Update Error 80244019 after long time searching for updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I have not updated my Windows system for over 5 months now (Windows 7, 64bit, SP1). This happened by mistake, not on purpose, because Windows update was set to install updates manually with prompting at 3:00 am.

Today I tried to install the updates. The following happened in sequence:

1. I started updating a set of files totalling to 400 Mb or so, but I had to cancle after 1 minute, because Windows had to restart for a different reason.
2. After restart, I started update manually again, but it hang on "preparing system for installation".
3. Subsequently I ran the Windows update fix tool: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/gp/windows-update-issues/en

This lead to a partial fix only. The tool ran unfortunately in German. It says "Windows update error" in the second row and the first two items say "not fixed"  [image]

4. I ran the update tool again. Now apparently it was reset, since the earlier runs were not visible anymore. I had to search for updates again, which took a long time (3 hours). Then it stopped with error 80244019. See image. It says in german unknown error 80244019. [image]
5. I am now trying to run fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810 right now, but this fix says "Searching for updates on this computer" and does not show progress so far.
6. After installation of this fix, Windows Update found and installed the updates successfully again.
7. However: it only find Windows updates and in fact it says "You receive updates: only for windows" on the start page. In fact I remember unchecking a box for "receiving updates for other Microsoft products" following an advice in this thread: [Windows Update fails with code 80244019](https://superuser.com/questions/965004/windows-update-fails-with-code-80244019). I did this before installing the MSU in step 5. Now, however, I cannot find this check box back in the MSU setting. See image. How can I now configure MSU to find MS Office updates etc.? [image]

Screenshot translation: There are only two check boxes: "Make available recommended updates in the same way as critical updates" and "Allow all users to install updates". An option to to switch on searching for other updates is missing.

**Edit**: I found a screenshot on MS Office Help which shows how MSU should look and in fact looked **before** I updated it in step 5. You can see that the checkbox for "other MS products" which is checked in the example disappeared. It is the box I unchecked before step 5. In fact there is another checkbox below the yellow marked area which also disappeared after the MSU update. Very strange.

[image]

Again I need your help; perhaps this is a new topic and would deserve a new thread, but because it occures following the fix of the 80244019 problem, I leave it here.

**EDIT 2:** I opened a new thread adressing the new issue described in step 7 only here: [Microsoft update (MSU) does not find updates for other Microsoft products (e.g. Office) after MSU update](https://superuser.com/questions/1044846/microsoft-update-msu-does-not-find-updates-for-other-microsoft-products-e-g)

Comment: [Run this fixit tool in aggressive mode](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9665683)

Comment: I cannot find the microsoft page for documentation, even google searching for fixit 9665683 does not help, it is a windows update reset tool made by microsoft, aggressive mode completely resets windows updates, cures many issues with windows updates.

Comment: 80244019 = WU_E_PT_HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND -  Same as HTTP status 404 - the server cannot find the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). For the hang at installing the MSU, use this workaround: http://superuser.com/a/1044548/174557

Comment: I made an update to the post. Installation of Windows updates was succesful. However, now no other Windows produc updates (e.g.MS office) are found and MSU cannot be configured to allow these. See screenshot. Somehow this checkbox disappeared after the MSU update. Any ideas?

Comment: Open Explorer
Go to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
Select all the files in this Download directory, and delete them
Then try the update. see if this helps at all.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Is this in response to step 7 (no other product updates found)? The issue that no MSU takes very long and produces errors is solved.

Comment: I see that now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Could you check out the new problem thread with the missing office updates please? Much appreciated :-) http://superuser.com/questions/1044846/microsoft-update-msu-does-not-find-updates-for-other-microsoft-products-e-g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the update problem install https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810.

To fix the missing checkbox problem after the update follow instructions in [Microsoft update (MSU) does not find updates for other Microsoft products (e.g. Office) after MSU update](https://superuser.com/questions/1044846/microsoft-update-msu-does-not-find-updates-for-other-microsoft-products-e-g).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill How could he quote the download link from that microsoft page? This answer suggests installing a patch from a linked page, what else could be possibly quoted?

Answer (score 2):

> This issue can be caused by Data Execution Protection being turned
>   Off.
>
> Hold the **Windows Key** and **Press R**. Type **sysdm.cpl** and Click
>   **OK**.
>
> Then click **Advanced** -> **Settings** -> **Data Execution
>   Protection**.
>
> Select **Turn on DEP for Essential Windows Programs and Services**
>   only and Click **Apply**. Click **OK**.
>
> Reboot your system, and now try updating.
>
> [80244019 error](http://appuals.com/windows-update-error-80244019/)